# SharePoint form fields no longer rendering after migration to 2019 from 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-form, sharepoint-list, 2019, classic-experience

I have migrated a custom list definition with custom list forms (New / Edit / Display) to SharePoint 2019 but the form fields are no longer displaying using the old method i.e using below code

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="Display" />
```

they work if I include the OOB listviewwebpart

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main" Style="display:none"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

However i did not have to include this in previous version of SharePoint  and would rather not load it if necessary as i only have to hide it then.

Has anyone come across similar issues in 2019 (the list is in classic mode not the modern UI).?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever come up with a solution. Adding the listviewwebpart to the page is a workaround but not very reliable